# How to hide content of a html element

Tags: javascript, jquery, hide

I have an "a" tag to which I've applied a background image.

Now I want to hide only the html content of the "a" tag, while I need the background and href address to remain there.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: You would be better off setting the background image to a parent div, so that you can hide the `<a>` without having to use logic or remove the content of it.

Comment: It sounds like you just need to replace the inner HTML of your anchor tag but providing code that shows what you're starting with and what you've already tried would help get a more succinct answer.

Comment: what do you mean, "link address"? the link you get in the status bar when you hover on the tag? or a link embedded in the `<a>`? e.g. `<a href="foo.html">this text to hide http://show.this.url more text to hide</a>`?

Comment: you can't do that. You should change the tag... don't use <a>

Comment: @SterlingArcher , I don't want to hide a tag,i need content of it's href

Comment: @MarcB ;I mean content of href

Comment: the href isn't displayed anywhere, except when you hover on it with the mouse. but even then that's not part of your page.

Comment: @MarcB; I just wanted when I click on image,which is background of a, the user be directed to address.however tanx!! solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work: $("#a_tag_id").html("");

Comment: Why should this work? The question is vague, making this answer very susceptible to being wrong

Comment: I know it's vague, just taking a stab at what he might be trying to do.

Comment: great!! it worked surprisingly!!

Comment: good to hear! If you could mark it as the accepted answer I would appreciate it. Thanks.